# How to add a value marker to JavaFX chart?

Tags: java, charts, javafx-2, javafx

I am trying to build a series chart using JavaFX, where data is inserted dynamically.

Each time that a new value is inserted I would like to check if this is the highest value so far, and if so, I want to draw an horizontal line to show that this is the maximum value.

In JFree chart I would have used a ValueMarker, but I am trying to do the same with JavaFX.

I tried using the Line object, but it is definitely not the same, because I cannot provide the Chart values, it takes the relative pixel positions in the windows.

Here is the screenshot of chart I want to achieve:

http://postimg.org/image/s5fkupsuz/

Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To convert chart values to pixels you can use method `NumberAxis#getDisplayPosition()` which return actual coordinates of the chart nodes.

Although these coordinates are relative to chart area, which you can find out by next code:

```
Node chartArea = chart.lookup(".chart-plot-background");
Bounds chartAreaBounds = chartArea.localToScene(chartArea.getBoundsInLocal());
```

Note `localToScene()` method which allows you to convert any coordinates to Scene ones. Thus you can use them to update your value marker coordinates. Make sure you make `localToScene` call after your Scene have been shown.

See sample program below which produces next chart:

[image]

```
public class LineChartValueMarker extends Application {

    private Line valueMarker = new Line();
    private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
    private NumberAxis yAxis;
    private double yShift;

    private void updateMarker() {
        // find maximal y value
        double max = 0;
        for (Data<Number, Number> value : series.getData()) {
            double y = value.getYValue().doubleValue();
            if (y > max) {
                max = y;
            }
        }
        // find pixel position of that value
        double displayPosition = yAxis.getDisplayPosition(max);
        // update marker
        valueMarker.setStartY(yShift + displayPosition);
        valueMarker.setEndY(yShift + displayPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(new NumberAxis(0, 100, 10), yAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 100, 10));

        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0, 0));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 20));

        chart.getData().addAll(series);
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.getChildren().addAll(chart, valueMarker);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

        // add new value on mouseclick for testing
        chart.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(series.getData().size() * 10, 30 + 50 * new Random().nextDouble()));
                updateMarker();
            }
        });

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        // find chart area Node
        Node chartArea = chart.lookup(".chart-plot-background");
        Bounds chartAreaBounds = chartArea.localToScene(chartArea.getBoundsInLocal());
        // remember scene position of chart area
        yShift = chartAreaBounds.getMinY();
        // set x parameters of the valueMarker to chart area bounds
        valueMarker.setStartX(chartAreaBounds.getMinX());
        valueMarker.setEndX(chartAreaBounds.getMaxX());
        updateMarker();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: btw, changed your code a bit to cope with resizable parents http://stackoverflow.com/a/24403761/203657

Comment: because such support should be handled by the chart itself :) Updating the marker in all environment changes can be cumbersome (apart from size/location changes, think f.i. disabled)

Comment: Oh, but you can't expect from software to support all features. I'd say it's great that this chart is easily expandable with new features.