# Determing JavaFX Chart Size using FXML

Tags: java, charts, javafx-2, fxml

I'm working on a value marker for a line chart in JavaFX 2.2. I therefore used the answer on an existing question here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615881/how-to-add-a-value-marker-to-javafx-chart) and the example by Sergey Grinev is working fine. However, if I want to use FXML to add a chart instead of adding it hardcoded I have problems determing the size of the chart's background.

I moved the initialization of the `chart` and the `valueMarker` to the `initialize()` method which the FXMLLoader automatically calls after the root element has been processed (see the note in the [JavaFX Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html)). But if I now use the following code to determine the size of the chart's background it returns just 0.0 for every bound value:

```
Node chartArea = chart.lookup(".chart-plot-background");
Bounds chartAreaBounds = chartArea.localToScene(chartArea.getBoundsInLocal());
```

The exact same code in the `updateMarker()` method returns the determined size of the chart's background on the second call. On the first call the bounds are set, but minX isn't correct. Here is my code:

```
public class LineChartValueMarker extends Application {

    @FXML
    private LineChart<Number, Number> chart;

    @FXML
    private Line valueMarker;

    @FXML
    private NumberAxis yAxis;

    private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();

    private void updateMarker() {
        Node chartArea = chart.lookup(".chart-plot-background");
        Bounds chartAreaBounds = chartArea.localToScene(chartArea
                .getBoundsInLocal());

        // SIZE OF THE CHART IS DETERMINED
        System.out.println(chartAreaBounds);

        valueMarker.setStartX(chartAreaBounds.getMinX());
        valueMarker.setEndX(chartAreaBounds.getMaxX());
    }

    public void initialize() {
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0, 0));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 20));

        chart.getData().addAll(series);

        // add new value on mouseclick for testing
        chart.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                series.getData().add(
                        new XYChart.Data(series.getData().size() * 10,
                                30 + 50 * new Random().nextDouble()));
                updateMarker();
            }
        });

        // find chart area Node
        Node chartArea = chart.lookup(".chart-plot-background");
        Bounds chartAreaBounds = chartArea.localToScene(chartArea
                .getBoundsInLocal());

        // SIZE AND POSITION OF THE CHART IS 0.0
        System.out.println(chartAreaBounds);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

        InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                "LineChartValueMarker.fxml");
        loader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
        loader.setLocation(this.getClass().getResource(
                "LineChartValueMarker.fxml"));

        Pane pane = (Pane) loader.load(in);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

I added upper case comments on the position in the code where I print the bounds (and I removed the update of the Y coordinate of the `valueMarker`). Here is the output:

```
BoundingBox [minX:0.0, minY:0.0, minZ:0.0, width:0.0, height:0.0, depth:0.0, maxX:0.0, maxY:0.0, maxZ:0.0]
BoundingBox [minX:45.0, minY:15.0, minZ:0.0, width:441.0, height:318.0, depth:0.0, maxX:486.0, maxY:333.0, maxZ:0.0]
BoundingBox [minX:37.0, minY:15.0, minZ:0.0, width:449.0, height:318.0, depth:0.0, maxX:486.0, maxY:333.0, maxZ:0.0]
```

The first output line comes from the `initialize()` method, the second line from the first call of `updateMarker()` (first mouseclick on the graph) and the third line from the second call of `updateMarker()` (second mouseclick on the graph) which finally returns the correct bound values of the chart's background.

Now my question: How or when can I determine the correct size of the chart's background (best in the `initialize()` method)? I hope there's someone who can help, because I have no explanation for this behavior. Thank you!