# JavaFX LineChart draw a red zone

Tags: java, javafx, linechart

[javafx] [linechart] fx8+

is possible to plot a red region in my linechart... i will explain this better

..i would give to the user a visible "red zone" for understand that a value is to highter than a fixed (final) value, in this case 1000

i can place a screen but not code, or i will be fired XD

[image: javafx linechart]

i spent about 2 hours for search a solution... any ideas?

Comment: You could just add a rectangle to the plot children: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871202/how-to-add-shapes-on-javafx-linechart?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Is a great idea... is not the solution for the answer but solved my specific problem..
how.. added a label on node when the value is hither then limit...
little code snippet for readers
XYChart.Data data=new XYChart.Data(time,value);
if(value>1000) data.setNode(new Label(""+value));

ty James!

Comment: But if all you want is a red region representing the "out of range" values, why not use the same technique to give you that?

Comment: Related, but slightly different: [How to add a value marker to JavaFX chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615881/how-to-add-a-value-marker-to-javafx-chart) and [Adding a line in a JavaFX chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232931/adding-a-line-in-a-javafx-chart)